# php,curl- print the list of directories and files and not of other webpage which is not a directory

Tags: php, curl, directory

i want $matches[1] to get the list of name of files and directory and not of other webpages.

```
 $link="some/remote/directory";

$ch = curl_init();
$hohoho ='$1'.$link.'$2$3';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$link );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128); // more progress info

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",$hohoho, $result);   


 if(preg_match('#<ul[^>]*>(.+?)</ul>#is', $result, $matches))
{foreach ($matches as &$match)

    $match = $match;
     echo '<ul>' . $matches[1] . '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: do you mean you need help parsing some HTML? in that case, we'd need a sample of your html. also FYI, you're doing it all wrong. look at DOMDocument, not preg_match

Comment: so what should i do? @hanshenrik

Comment: show us the HTML you're trying to parse

Comment: i'm trying to get these type of html pages http://www.apfuns.com/apfunz/Pop%20Remix%20And%20Bangra/Sad%20Songs/Sad%20Punjabi%20Vol%202/

and don't want to curl any other type of page @hanshenrik

Comment: easy, but not a regex-job. use something like DOMDocument. example: . `<?php $ch=curl_init();curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_URL=>'http://www.apfuns.com/apfunz/Pop%20Remix%20And%20Bangra/Sad%20Songs/Sad%20Punjabi%20Vol%202/',CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true));$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));$files=array();foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("a") as $file){$files[]=trim(file->textContent);}header("content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8");print_r($files); ?>`

Comment: and how do i keep directories like http://www.apfuns.com/apfunz/Pop%20Remix%20And%20Bangra/Sad%20Songs/

and files like these
http://www.apfuns.com/apfunz/Pop%20Remix%20And%20Bangra/Sad%20Songs/Sad%20Punjabi%20Vol%202/

inside one array with their original links intact and not ANY OTHER WEBPAGE inside the array @hanshenrik
or maybe set a condition which curl only these type of pages and not any other.